# How to process subarrays in each routine OpenMP

Tags: c++, arrays, parallel-processing, openmp

I have some code, that parallel calculate the sums of some array's prefixes (ex. `out_arr[0]` = `in_arr[0]`, `out_arr[1]` = `in_arr[0]+in_arr[1]` .. etc).
My code has the `N` threads, there `N` is a number of `in_arr` elements and each thread process only 1 element of array. This is not good solution, so I want to process `N/num_of_threads` in each thread, but I've failed.

I tried to create shared variable with `N/num_of_threads` value and organize `for` cycle with this variable right of behind 1st `#pragma` directive, but I couldn't debug those magic numbers in stdout.

This is working version of «bad» solution:

```
void CalcSum2(int a[], int s[], int n) { 
    int* old = new int [n], *cnt = new int [n]; 
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(N) {
    int i = omp_get_thread_num(), d = 1; 
    s[i] = a[i]; 
    cnt[i] = 1; 
     #pragma omp barrier 
    while (d < n) { 
        old[i] = s[i]; 
     #pragma omp barrier 
         if (i >= d) { 
             s[i] += old[i-d]; 
         cnt[i]++; 
         } 
         d += d; 
     #pragma omp barrier 
    }
    }
    delete[] old; delete[] cnt; 
    return; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a cumulative sum. Also know as a prefix sum. This can be done in parallel with OpenMP.  I solved this problem recently with OpenMP [Parallel cumulative (prefix) sums in OpenMP: communicating values between threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719257/parallel-cumulative-prefix-sums-in-openmp-communicating-values-between-thread)

You have to run over the array twice in parallel.  The first time does partial sums and the second time corrects the partial sums with an offset.

I converted your code to to this for you below.  As as test I did the sum of the counting number which has a closed form solution of `i*(i+1)/2`.  You can see that the prefix_sum function get's the right answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void prefix_sum(int a[], int s[], int n) {
    int *suma;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        const int ithread = omp_get_thread_num();
        const int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        #pragma omp single
        {
            suma = new int[nthreads+1];
            suma[0] = 0;
        }
        int sum = 0;
        #pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait // do partial sum in parallel
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            sum += a[i];
            s[i] = sum;
        }
        suma[ithread+1] = sum;
        #pragma omp barrier
        int offset = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<(ithread+1); i++) {
            offset += suma[i];
        }

        #pragma omp for schedule(static) //run over array again in parallel for full sum
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            s[i] += offset;
        }
    }
    delete[] suma;
}

int main() {
    const int n = 100;
    int *a = new int[n];
    int *s = new int[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    prefix_sum(a, s, n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", s[i]);
    } printf("\n");

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", i*(i+1)/2);
    } printf("\n");
}
```

**Edit**
One of the problems of this method is that for large arrays most of the values have been evicted from the cache by the time the second pass starts.  I came up with a solution which runs over a chunk in parallel and then moves on to the next chunk sequentially.  I set the chunck_size to the level-2 cache (actually times four due to having four cores).  This gives a big improvement for larger arrays.  Here is an outline of the function.  The complete function can be found in my answer at [simd-prefix-sum-on-intel-cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587598/simd-prefix-sum-on-intel-cpu/19496697#19496697).

```
void scan_omp_SSEp2_SSEp1_chunk(float a[], float s[], int n) {
    float *suma;
    const int chunk_size = 1<<18;
    const int nchunks = n%chunk_size == 0 ? n / chunk_size : n / chunk_size + 1;    
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        //initialization code 
        for (int c = 0; c < nchunks; c++) {
            const int start = c*chunk_size;
            const int chunk = (c + 1)*chunk_size < n ? chunk_size : n - c*chunk_size; 
            //pass1: pass1_SSE(&a[start], &s[start], chunk);                
            //get offset
            //pass2: pass2_SSE(&s[start], offset, chunk);
        }
    }
    delete[] suma;
}
```

Comment: fewer barriers can reduce the thread overhead, but when `ithreads` is 0, `offset` is 0, you could save `n/nthreads` unnecessary addition operations to improve the performance, especially when nthreads is 1 or 2.

Comment: That's interesting.  Let me think about that.

Comment: By doing n/m less additions the time cost becomes `2n/m - n/m^2` (where m=nthreads).  Compared to `2n/m` that's a `1/(2m)` decrease in the time.  For m=2 that's 25%, for m=3  16%, m=4 12%.  For two cores systems it might be worth worrying about but then the improvement is still at best 25%.  Probably the extra code would wash it out.  Parallel prefix sums on a two core system are probably not worth doing.  I would have to change my code significantly to do this with OpenMP as well.

Answer (score 1):

The way you parallel the scan uses too many barriers which can hurt the performance.

Parallel scan on multi-core CPU is not very efficient because the number of sum operations increases from `n-1` to about `2n`. So the time cost is `2n/m`, where `m` is the number of CPU cores.

To reduce the number of barriers, you could first do sequential scan on each segment of the data, then add a proper offset to each segment result. The following code demos the idea. It got **2.4x** speed up on 8-core CPU when `len` is 1G. You could still improve the second part to get higher performance.

```
inline void scan(int a[], int s[], int len)
{
    int sum=0.0;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
        sum+=a[i];
        s[i]=sum;
    }
}

void ParallelScan(int a[], int s[], int len)
{
    int nt;
    int seglen, subseglen;
    int* segsum;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            nt = omp_get_num_threads();
            seglen = (len+nt-1)/nt;
            subseglen = (seglen+nt-1)/nt;
            segsum = new int[nt];
        }
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        int start = seglen*tid;
        int end = seglen*(tid+1);
        end = end > len ? len : end;

        scan(&a[start],&s[start],end-start);
        segsum[tid]=s[end-1];
        #pragma omp barrier

        #pragma omp single
        for(int i=1; i<nt; i++) {
            segsum[i]+=segsum[i-1];
        }

        for(int segid=1; segid<nt; segid++) {
            int segstart=seglen*segid;
            int start = segstart + subseglen*tid;
            int end = start + subseglen;
            end = end > len ? len : end;
            end = end > segstart+seglen ? segstart+seglen : end;

            int offset = segsum[segid-1];
            for(int i=start; i<end; i++) {
                s[i]+=offset;
            }
        }
    }


    delete[] segsum;
}
```

Comment: Is that really an 8 core CPU or is it 4 cores and 8 hyper threads?  What CPU is it?

Comment: @redrum 8 core. I changed the data type to `int` and got a even worse result.

Comment: You changed the length size to 1GB which is main memory bound.  That's likely the reason for the drop from 3.5 to only 2.5 faster.  Since the best is 2n/m and you have 8 cores the best you can expect is 4 times faster.  You got 3.5 originally.  That's not bad.

Comment: +1 for stating the time cost `2n/m` and for suggestion the 2nd order correction.

Comment: sorry to belabor this point but you're time cost formula `2n/m` is only true if the second pass is not vectorized.  If it is then the time cost will be closer to `n/m` but still greater than `n/m`.

Comment: That's an rough estimation of the total number of operation 'plus', of course you can use Vectorization to reduce the number of instructions and clock cycles.