# Parallel sum of corresponding elements of arrays stored sequentially in OpenMP

Tags: c++, arrays, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a number of arrays of which I would like to sum elements at corresponding positions into a "results" array with the same number of elements as the originals.  The arrays I am trying to add together are stored in a vector.

That is R = A0 + A1 + ... + AN where R and all Ai are arrays of the same size.

I can't post images, so here's [a link illustrating the situation](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90313754/img.png).

What is the best way to do this computation in parallel with OpenMP (C++)?  I'd like to take advantage of SIMD if possible, but really I'd appreciate any direction at all.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this question covers the sort of thing you're trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413995/reducing-on-array-in-openmp

Comment: @Theolodus: The question isn't exactly the same, but the answers there look like they may be able to be modified for this situation.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you don't have data race... 
That means using #pragma omp parallel for simd.

Comment: My understanding is that the results array is shared between several threads that write to all elements of the results array, and there is thus a potential race.  Am I incorrect?

Comment: Yes, several threads write the same array, but different elments of this result array.  Elements of an array have different physical addresses, i.e. different memory cells.  Data race happens, only if a single memory cell, such as an cell for an integer, is written by several threads.