# User Defined Reduction on vector of varying size

Tags: c++, vector, openmp

I'm trying to define my own reduction for vectors of complex<float>, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28234148/463827) to the question [Reducing on array in OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413995/reducing-on-array-in-openmp).

But the size of my vectors aren't fixed at compile time, so I'm not sure how to define the initializer for the vector in the `declare reduction` pragma.  That is, I can't just have

```
initializer( omp_priv=TComplexVector(10,0) )
```

But the initializer is needed for vectors.

How can I pass the initializer clause the size of the vector I need at run time?  What I have so far is below:

```
typedef std::vector<complex<float>> TCmplxVec;

void ComplexAdd(TCmplxVec & x,TCmplxVec & y){
  for (int i=0;i<x.size();i++) 
  {
      x.real()+= y.real();
      //... same for imaginary part and other operations
  }

}

#pragma omp declare reduction(AddCmplx: TCmplxVec: \
ComplexAdd(&omp_out, &omp_in)) initializer( \
omp_priv={TCmplxVec(**here I want a variable length**,0} )

void DoSomeOperation ()
{
    //TCmplxVec vec is empty and anotherVec not

    //so each thread runs the inner loop serially
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(AddCmplx: vec) 
  for ( n=0 ; n<10 ; ++n )
    {
      for (m=0; m<=someLength; ++m){
        vec[m] += anotherVec[m+someOffset dependend on n and else];
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your questions sounds like I could be interesting but I really don't know what you're asking. You need more code less words and the code needs to be general and should not contain details only you are likely to know about.

Comment: To give it your own length instead of `int S_private[10] = {0};` do `int *S_private = new int[n]()` and then after the critical section do `delete[] S_private`.

Comment: Also I get the felling by vector you don't mean a dynamic array (std::vector) but a math vector. You taged [vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vector) which is for dynamic arrays. Is this really what you want? Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: Hello, I have added some piece of code. I hope it is somehow easier to understand. I use the std::vector for FFT calculations, also misusing them for the fftw-functions, because since the latest version accepts overlaoding their types with own types like above

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to dig a little bit to find it online right now, but in section 2.15 of the [OpenMP Standard](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf), where user-declared reductions are discussed, you'll find that "The special identifier omp_orig can also appear in the initializer-clause and it will refer to the storage of the original variable to be reduced."

So you could use `initializer (omp_priv=TCmplxVec(omp_orig.size(),0))`, or just `initalizer ( omp_priv(omp_orig) )` to initialize the vector in the reduction.

So the following works (note that you don't need to write your own routine; you can use std::transform and std::plus to add your vectors; you could also use std::valarray rather than vectors, depending on how you use them, which has operator+ already defined):

```
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

typedef std::vector< std::complex<float> > TCmplxVec;

#pragma omp declare reduction( + : TCmplxVec : \
        std::transform(omp_in.begin( ),  omp_in.end( ), \
                       omp_out.begin( ), omp_out.begin( ), \
                       std::plus< std::complex<float> >( )) ) \
                       initializer (omp_priv(omp_orig))

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int size;

    if (argc < 2)
        size = 10;
    else
        size = atoi(argv[1]);

    TCmplxVec result(size,0);

    #pragma omp parallel reduction( + : result )
    {
        int tid=omp_get_thread_num();

        for (int i=0; i<std::min(tid+1,size); i++) 
            result[i] += tid;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) 
        std::cout << i << "\t" << result[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Running this gives

```
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./reduction 8
0   (0,0)
1   (0,0)
2   (0,0)
3   (0,0)
4   (0,0)
5   (0,0)
6   (0,0)
7   (0,0)

$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./reduction 8
0   (6,0)
1   (6,0)
2   (5,0)
3   (3,0)
4   (0,0)
5   (0,0)
6   (0,0)
7   (0,0)

$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 ./reduction 8
0   (28,0)
1   (28,0)
2   (27,0)
3   (25,0)
4   (22,0)
5   (18,0)
6   (13,0)
7   (7,0)
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer and the reference link to the OpenMP standard!