# Openmp and reduction on std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, parallel-processing, openmp, reduction

I want to make this code parallel:

```
std::vector<float> res(n,0);
std::vector<float> vals(m);
std::vector<float> indexes(m);
// fill indexes with values in range [0,n)
// fill vals and indexes
for(size_t i=0; i<m; i++){
  res[indexes[i]] += //something using vas[i];
}
```

In [this](https://decvalts.github.io/2016/11/06/OpenMP-array_reduction.html) article it's suggested to use:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:myArray[:6])
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413995/reducing-on-array-in-openmp) question the same approach is proposed in the comments section.

I have two questions:

1. I don't know `m` at compile time, and from these two examples it seems that's required. Is it so? Or if I can use it for this case, what do I have to replace `?` with in the following command `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:res[:?])` ? `m` or `n`?
2. Is it relevant that the indexes of the `for` are relative to `indexes` and `vals` and not to `res`, especially considering that `reduction` is done on the latter one?

However,  If so, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is fairly straight forward to do a user declared reduction for C++ vectors of a specific type:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#pragma omp declare reduction(vec_float_plus : std::vector<float> : \
                              std::transform(omp_out.begin(), omp_out.end(), omp_in.begin(), omp_out.begin(), std::plus<float>())) \
                    initializer(omp_priv = decltype(omp_orig)(omp_orig.size()))

std::vector<float> res(n,0);
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(vec_float_plus : res)
for(size_t i=0; i<m; i++){
    res[...] += ...;
}
```

1a) Not knowing `m` at compile time is not a requirement.

1b) You cannot use the array section reduction on `std::vector`s, because they are not arrays (and `std::vector::data` is not an identifier). If it were possible, you'd have to use `n`, as this is the number of elements in the array section.

2) As long as you are only reading `indexes` and `vals`, there is no issue.

Edit: The original `initializer` caluse was simpler: `initializer(omp_priv = omp_orig)`. However, if the original copy is then not full of zeroes, the result will be wrong. Therefore, I suggest the more complicated initializer which always creates zero-element vectors.

Comment: Omp reduction asserts that the compiler need not take care of data overlaps in the case of duplicate indirect indices.

Comment: @time18 I don't understand what you mean. Could you elaborate? There is a private copy of `res` for each thread, so there is no issue if there are duplicate indirect indices.

Comment: @Zulan Thanks for your answer. Could you please give a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193566/omp-reduction-on-vector-of-cvmat-or-cvmat-in-general) ?

Comment: If we first resize vec to `n`, and then set the elements just like an array, without defining user-declared-reduction, will this involve `false-sharing` and slow down the performance?

Comment: Just wanted to add: be careful when using this inside a `parallel` region. Then, either a `scope` clause (which isn't supported much yet) or a loop over all threads is necessary to achieve correct results.