# OpenMP with ++ increment in 2d array

Tags: c++, openmp, increment

I have two large 1-dimensional input arrays (`input_array1` and `input_array2`) with billions of elements with values, ranging from 0 to 100, and one output 2-dimensional array (`array_101x101`) with 101 rows and 101 columns. Rows in output array correspond to values in `input_array1`; columns in output array correspond to values in `input_array2`. Cells in output 101x101 array contain count of each combination of values in input arrays. How to use `++` increment with pragma, if I increment array's elements, but not a single variable?

Here is the code:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma omp parallel for private(array_101x101) reduction(+:array_101x101) num_threads(50) schedule(static, 1000)

for (i = 0; i < i_length; i++)
 {
  array_101x101[input_array1[i]][input_array2[i]]++;
 }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It returns the following error message when compiling:

```
error: ‘array_101x101’ appears more than once in data clauses
#pragma omp parallel for private(array_101x101) reduction(+:array_101x101) num_threads(50) schedule(static, 1000)
```

I tried to increment without `reduction(+:array_101x101)`. It can be compiled and run, but it returns wrong result - not all cases were counted.

**UPDATE**
1-d array reduction worked for me. I also tried to implement class-based approach. It returns error message when compiling:  error: user defined reduction not found for ‘mybin’

What's wrong in the code with class and how to make it working?:

```
class bin101
 {
  public:
   unsigned long int array_101x101[101][101];
 };

int main()
 {
  bin101 mybin;
  unsigned char input_array2[i_length];
  unsigned char input_array1[i_length];
  // loading data to input_array1 and 2

  #pragma omp parallel reduction(+:mybin) 
  for (i = 0; i < i_length; i++)
   {
     mybin.array_101x101[input_array2[i]][input_array1[i]]++;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Setting `num_threads(50)` manually is often a bad idea. Besides, do you have >=50 available cores? If yes, then you need to care about NUMA effects (many-cores systems tends to have multiple NUMA nodes). Otherwise it can be slower than using less threads.

Comment: What is the type of `array_101x101`? If it is a jagged array, then it is not efficient. You should use a flatten array. Alternatively, an `std::array<std::array<..., nx>, ny>` is fine (but not `std::vector<std::vector<...>>`)

Comment: I have two servers with 56 and 128 cores, so, yes I have 50 available cores.

array_101x101 is a simple dynamic 2-d array:

unsigned long int **array_101x101 = new unsigned long int*[101];
  for ( a = 0; a < 101; a++) {array_101x101[a] = new unsigned long int [101];}

Comment: This is not a 2D array but a jagged array and they are inefficient because of their memory layout. Static 2D array in C/C++ are flatten internally, that is, the compiler allocate 101x101 items on the stack at once. With dynamic array you should do it yourself (this is very common) : `array_101x101 = new long int[101*101];`. You should then change the indexing (`array_101x101[i*101+j]`). Some scientific libraries like Eigen should be able to do that for you.

Comment: Regarding your CPU, AFAIK AMD is the only mainstream vendor to design 128 core CPUs so far. AMD CPUs are NUMA ones. Basically, this means that if your array are filled with a sequential code, they are stored on only one NUMA node. Thus, accessing the big arrays later in parallel will saturate the NUMA node where the big arrays are stored (typically a bottleneck). This is something to consider for the sake of performance.

Comment: C++23 has `std::mdspan` to make it nice and easy to get a multi-dimensional view of one-dimensional memory. MS VS seems to completely support it already while clang has partial support (probably enough for this case) and gcc doesn't support it yet according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23).

Comment: Putting `#pragma openmp atomic update` in front of the `++` operation should give correct results, but is most probably worse in terms of performance than using a proper reduction.

Comment: You seem to have missed point 3 in Victor's answer: You need to implement `bin101::operator+(const bin101&)`.

Answer (score 3):

You think you have a problem with openmp syntax, and that is correct: if you reduce into an array, it can not be private, EDIT in fact, it can not be in any shared/private/firstprivate/... clause. So it kinda looks like shared-by-default. Which makes sense, right?

Your bigger problem is that your algorithm suffers from major race conditions: you're mapping from a really long array into a much shorter, so you get write conflicts out the wazoo. If you fixed your syntax problems you'd see that you get completely incorrect results.

Fortunately you are writing C++ so the solution is fairly doable.

1. Take your `array_101x101` and encapsulate it in a class; call it `bin101` or so.
2. Give objects in this class an indexing operator `[i,j]` that returns a reference so that you can `++` on it. You can now write your loop unchanged.
3. For the big trick: you need to write `bin101::operator+(const bin101&)` which adds two of these bin objects together.

And now you can create a `bin101 mybin` object and

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:mybin)
```

This will in effect give each thread a local bin object (so that's a little extra memory!) and into which it does a conflict-free local count; then the plus operator adds these local counts together. This approach is almost completely parallel without any critical section or anything to resolve conflicts, because there aren't any.

NOTE This approach can also be made to work with C, if you write a reduction function and then `declare reduction`. But using the C++ machinery is just so much more elegant. @PierU sketches a solution with local maps and a critical region: a declared reduction operator will be more efficient since it uses a reduction tree.

Comment: `array_101x101` must not be shared either. A variable that appears in a `reduction` clause must not appear in any other clause such as `shared`, `private`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

A variable that appears in a `reduction` clause must not appear in other clauses such as `private`, `shared`, etc... The compiler does what is needed to perform the reduction, including a hidden privatisation of the variable.

You may be then tempted to write `reduction(+:array_101x101)`, but by doing so you wouldn't ask for a reduction on the elements of the array, but on the pointer itself (and the compiler won't let you do that).

In C/C++ <strike>there's no direct support for OpenMP reductions on arrays (as opposed to Fortran)</strike>. Victor Eijkhout as suggested an approach with a class, there is another one that consists in performing the reduction manually:

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    long int* private_array = new long int[101*101];
    for (int i=0; i<101*101; i++) private_array[i] = 0;

    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < i_length; i++) {
        private_array[input_array1[i]*101 + input_array2[i]]++;
    }

    #pragma omp critical
    for (int j=0; j<101; j++) {
        for (int i=0; j<101; j++) {
            array_101x101[j][i] = array_101x101[j][i] + private_array[j*101 + i];
        }
    }

    delete private_array;
}
```

It will be less performant than an automatic reduction, though.

### EDIT

@Paleonix reminded me in the comments that there is actually some support for array reduction, at least for 1D arrays. I makes things simpler, but you'd better declare your array as 1D from the start:

```
long int* array_101x101 = new long int[101*101];
for (int i=0; i<101*101; i++) array_101x101[i] = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:array_101x101[:101*101])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < i_length; i++) {
        array_101x101[input_array1[i]*101 + input_array2[i]]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is support for array reduction since OpenMP 4.5, at least considering 1D arrays. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66714116/10107454). C++ operator overloading just gives more control over what happens.

Comment: @paleonix My bad, I forgot that... I have updated the answer

Comment: Just to point out that my class-based solution uses the built-in reduction tree of OMP, so it will be a little more efficient than your critical region. I have not benchmarked whether this difference is actually noticable, since it concerns a lower order of data.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Indeed, I did write that the manual reduction is likely less performant

Comment: Thank you, paleonix and PierU. The last EDIT worked for me well. Short and clear. I got correct count of combinations. Class-based solution, suggested by Victor Eijkhout, though maybe more efficient, is more challenging for me to implement without an example of a code. I have not studied OOP yet.