# Parallel computing for prefix sum using openMP (c code)

Tags: c, parallel-processing, cygwin, openmp, prefix-sum

Have some problems with assigning parallel algorithm to prefix sum issue. I am using openMP for parallel implementation. I have the code in c as below.

Result showing:

```
seqsum[6] = 28 != parallelsum[6] = 34
```

Please advise. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "omp.h"
#include <string.h>
#define N 10 //33554432 // 2 ^ 25
#define NUM_THREADS 4 

void computeparallelprefix(int *iplist, int *_pprefixsum, unsigned long size)
{
  int nthr, *z, *x = _pprefixsum;
  int i, j, tid, work, lo, hi;
#pragma omp parallel shared(nthr,x,z) private(i,j,tid,work,lo,hi)
  {
    int prev_sum;
    memcpy((void *)x, (void *)iplist, sizeof(int)*size);

    // Assume nthr = 2^k
#pragma omp single
    {
      nthr = omp_get_num_threads();
      z = malloc(sizeof(int)*nthr);
    }   
    tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    work = size /nthr + (i = tid < size%nthr ? 1 : 0);
    lo = (size/nthr)*tid + (i==1 ? tid : size%nthr);
    hi = lo + work;
    if (hi > size)
      hi = size;

    // local prefix sum over x
    for(i=lo+1; i<hi; i++)
      x[i] += x[i-1];    

    // local prefix sum for tid
    z[tid] = x[hi-1];
#pragma omp barrier


    // global prefix sum over z
    for(j=1; j<nthr; j=2*j) {
      if (tid >= j)
        z[tid] = z[tid] + z[tid-j];
#pragma omp barrier
    } 

    // Update local prefix sum x
    prev_sum = z[tid] - x[hi-1];
    for(i=lo;i<hi;i++)
      x[i] += prev_sum;
  }
  free(z);
}

void initlist(int *iplist, unsigned long size)
{
  int i;
  for ( i = 0; i < size; i++)
    iplist[i] = i+1;
  //     iplist[i] = rand() % 13;
}

void printlist(int *list, unsigned long size)
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%d ", list[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void computeseqprefixsum(int *iplist, int *seqprefixsum, unsigned long size)
{
  int i;
  seqprefixsum[0] = iplist[0];
  for(i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    seqprefixsum[i] = seqprefixsum[i-1] + iplist[i];
  }
}

void checkresults(int *seqsum, int *parallelsum, unsigned long size)
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if(seqsum[i] != parallelsum[i]) {
      printf("seqsum[%d] = %d != parallelsum[%d] = %d\n", i, seqsum[i], i,
          parallelsum[i]);
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // seed the rand generator
  srand(time(NULL));
  double seqstart, seqend, parstart, parend, seqtime, partime;

  // initialize list

  int *iplist, *seqprefixsum, *pprefixsum ;

  iplist = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
  seqprefixsum = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
  pprefixsum = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * N);

  if(iplist == NULL || seqprefixsum == NULL || pprefixsum == NULL) {
    printf("memory cannot be allocated\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  initlist(iplist, N);

  seqstart = omp_get_wtime();

  computeseqprefixsum(iplist, seqprefixsum, N);

  seqend = omp_get_wtime();

  seqtime = seqend - seqstart;

  omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);

  parstart = omp_get_wtime();

  computeparallelprefix(iplist, pprefixsum, N);

  parend= omp_get_wtime();

  partime = parend - parstart;

  checkresults(seqprefixsum, pprefixsum, N);

  printf("Seq Time : %f, Par Time : %f, Speedup : %f\n", seqtime, partime,
      seqtime/partime);

  free(iplist); free(seqprefixsum); free(pprefixsum);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: due to the data dependency in the calculation , I think it the problem is hard to parallelize from the start

Comment: How can I improve it? Thanks

Comment: you really cannot parallelize your computeseqprefixsum because each value is depending on the previous one

Comment: @dvhh, it's not too difficult to parallelize in two passes. The first pass you do partial sums for each thread and in the second pass you correct with an offset for each thread. The problem is not getting a parallel algorithm it's that the operation is memory bandwidth bound (like many operations) and so it does not scale with with the number of physical cores.

Comment: @dvhh, in fact that's exactly what the OP is doing: two passes, first is partial, second is a correction.  Here's a working example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719257/parallel-cumulative-prefix-sums-in-openmp-communicating-values-between-thread. I'm not sure why the OPs code is not working but it's the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea for the prefix sum with your code.

I'm not sure exactly why you don't get the correct result but I cleaned up your code and my version gets the correct result.  See the following question for more details [parallel-cumulative-prefix-sums-in-openmp-communicating-values-between-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719257/parallel-cumulative-prefix-sums-in-openmp-communicating-values-between-thread)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "omp.h"
#define N 11 //33554432 // 2 ^ 25

void computeparallelprefix(int *iplist, int *_pprefixsum, unsigned long size)
{
  int nthr, *z, *x = _pprefixsum;
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    int i;
    #pragma omp single
    {
      nthr = omp_get_num_threads();
      z = malloc(sizeof(int)*nthr+1);
      z[0] = 0;
    }
    int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    int sum = 0;
    #pragma omp for schedule(static) 
    for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
      sum += iplist[i];
      x[i] = sum;
    }
    z[tid+1] = sum;
    #pragma omp barrier

    int offset = 0;
    for(i=0; i<(tid+1); i++) {
        offset += z[i];
    }

    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
    for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
      x[i] += offset;
    }
  }
  free(z);
}

int main(void ) {

  int *iplist, *pprefixsum ;

  iplist = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
  pprefixsum = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * N);

  for(int i=0; i<N; i++) iplist[i] = i+1;
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%d ", iplist[i]); printf("\n");

  computeparallelprefix(iplist, pprefixsum, N);
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%d ", pprefixsum[i]); printf("\n");
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%d ", (i+1)*(i+2)/2); printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! However, it still not works at my end. All progma commands are not functional at all: error: invalid preprocessing directive #progma

Comment: @Orangeblue, what are you talking about? There is no `#progma` in my code. I just compiled with `-Wall` and I get no warnings. I also grepped for `progma` which returned nothing. This code is fine. I compiled with `gcc -std=gnu99 -fopenmp -O3 -Wall psum.c`

Comment: It seems one thread was allowed to malloc "z", but every thread to free the memory "z".

Comment: @Zboson: Orangeblue has [suggested an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7482112) to change all the `#pragma` to `#progma`.

Comment: @NisseEngström, his edit should be rejected. What is `#progma`?

Comment: @NisseEngström, his own quesiton uses `#pragma`.