# Omp for loop initialize vector

Tags: c++, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

I have the following code:

```
int main() {
vector<int> vec;

#pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(dynamic)            
for (int i = 0; i <= 300; i++) {
    vec.push_back(i);
} 
cout << vec.size() << endl;
}
```

The vector size is sometimes 285 or 294, but never 301. What i doing wrong?

Comment: No expert with OMP, but I am afraid that's because `vec.push_back(i);` isn't a thread safe operation.

Comment: You're most probably encountering a data race. Imagine two threads trying to to `push_back` a vector simultaneously. It's not a good thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parallelizing a for loop using openmp & replacing push\_back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765180/parallelizing-a-for-loop-using-openmp-replacing-push-back)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing here is the effect of a thread unsafe function being called by multiple threads. Internally `push_back` does something like the following in pseudocode

```
if reallocation needed:
    reallocate
construct new object at &data[size]
++size
```

Now try to imagine different threads running the above code at the same time. What happens if both threads see the need to reallocate and attempt to do so at the same time. What if they both construct an object at `&data[size]` because they both reached that point before `++size`? Note that even trying to increment on the same line as the construction won't work because they are still separate non-atomic operations.

What you really want to do is create a loop of strictly thread safe operations like the following.

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec(301);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i <= 300; i++) {
        vec[i]= i;
    }
    std::cout << vec.size() << std::endl;
}
```

In this case, every thread accesses `vec[i]` with a unique `i`. So no operations ever happen concurrently to the same objects. This is absolutely safe.

To answer your follow-up question, there is no way to `push_back` concurrently into a vector. You would have to synchronize your `push_back` calls which would make them slower than the non-parallel way. Another solution is to populate thread-local containers and then merge them. But whenever the simple solution I showed above is applicable it will also be faster than the alternatives.