# OpenMP through std::set using iterator

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, stdset

I have a mesh with huge number of segments, I want to apply filter and fill `std::set set_`, which is private member of class `A`. There is function called `fill_vec()` which is going to fill the vector using a `for` loop:

```
fill_set()
{
  for(mesh::SegIterator it = A.beginSeg(); it != A.endSeg(); ++it )
  {
    mesh::Segment Seg_ = *it;
    int SignP = 0;
    int SignN = 0;


    for(mesh::PointIterator itp = Seg_.beginPoint(); itp != Seg_.endPoint(); ++itp )
    {
      double old_, new_;
      ... 
      ...

      if( old_ > 0.0 && new_ > 0.0 )
        SignP++;
      if( old_ < 0.0 && new_ < 0.0 )
        SignN++;
    }
    if( (SignP == 1 && SignN == 1) || (SignP == 1 && SignN == 2) )
    {
      set_.insert(Seg_);
    }
}
```

I am trying peform above code in parallel using OpenMP and C++03. I saw some solutions like as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669296/c-openmp-parallel-for-loop-alternatives-to-stdvector/18671256#18671256). Any other safe and neat solution?

Comment: Is mesh::SegIterator a RandomAccessIterator or just a BidirectionalIterator (or even just a ForwardIterator)?

Comment: I don't see why you can't use the same techniques [I described for std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669296/c-openmp-parallel-for-loop-alternatives-to-stdvector/18671256#18671256). Write private sets for each thread and the merge them with `insert` in a critical section.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing from `it != A.endSeg()` to `it < A.endSeg()`. The problem with `!=` is the loop is not *countable*. The compiler can't know for sure that the loop will ever end. Switching it to `<` should make it countable.

Comment: You would also need a critical section around the `set_.insert(Seg_);` line, as std containers cannot be resized asynchronously.

Comment: Good catch. @GuyGreer