# OPEN MP, Container for threads

Tags: c++, vector, openmp

Heyho,

i've been using omp for some time and i wonder, whether there is a good way to storage data. Something like a reduce function for std::vector or anything like that would be perfect.

Anyway...Which container is save? I used std::vector>, but there were some problems with push_back. I had to resize my vector first an than change to content. I am sure that there has to be a better way.
Thanks for any sugestions.

P.S.

I beg for pardon. My english isn't that good.

Comment: AFAIK none of the stl containers is threadsafe (please correct me if I'm wrong). You have to either write something yourself or search for a available solution. The first thing that comes to my mind is TBB.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I think I have to learn more about TBB. omp fits just perfectly, if someone gives you the task to add some parallelization to your serial code. I still hope there is another good way.

Comment: It is no problem to use openmp for the parallel logic and a tbb container as storage though tbb is capable of doing both.

Comment: Now i really have to learn more about TBB! Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669296/c-openmp-parallel-for-loop-alternatives-to-stdvector/18671256#18671256