# How to write "target data map" for std::vector in OpenMP 4?

Tags: c++, vector, openmp, pragma

I want to use C++ and `vectors`. I had C code with C arrays created like this:

```
double* data = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
double* result = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * n);

#pragma omp target data map(tofrom: data[0:n],result[0:n])
//loop
```

Now I use C++ vector and I get:

```
example.cpp:31:41: error: expected variable name or an array item
    #pragma omp target data map(tofrom: data[0:n],result[0:n])
```

Here they say [OpenMP4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18671256/1973207) introduced  user-defined reductions. But have it any analogs for data maps?

Answer (score 4):

You could always get the pointers of the underlying storage of `std::vector` and then use them in the same way as in your C code.

```
double* data = vec_data.data();
double* result = vec_res.data();
int n = vec_data.size();

#pragma omp target data map(tofrom:data[0:n],result[0:n])
//loop
```