# conditionally filling a vector in parallel

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, vector

I'd like to write a multi-threaded version of the following code

```
template<typename Out, typename In, typename Cond, typename Func>
std::vector<Out> collect(std::vector<In> const&values,
                         Cond const&cond, Func const&func)
{
    std::vector<Out> result;
    for(auto const&val : values)
        if(cond(val))
            result.emplace_back(func(val));
    return result;
}
```

where the order of selected elements does not matter.

One simple approach is

```
template<typename Out, typename In, typename Cond, typename Func>
std::vector<Out> collect(std::vector<In> const&values,
                         Cond const&cond, Func const&func)
{
    std::vector<Out> result(values.size());
    std::atomic<size_t> index = 0;
    // some multithreaded for loop implementation
    parallel_for(size_t(0),values.size(),[&](size_t i) {
        if(cond(values[i]))
            result[index++] = func(values[i]);
    });
    result.resize(index);
    return result;
}
```

(of course, initializing `result` is serial, but let's ignore that here). This appears to work, but may not be lock-free. Is there a better way? In particular, can I avoid allocating too many data (if only a few input data get selected)?

The problem is very similar to `std::copy_if` (it would be `std::transform_if` it that existed) -- how is the parallel version [`std::copy_if(std::par,...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) implemented (which is C++17, but I'm restricted to C++11)?

Comment: i wouldnt make all threads write to the same vector, but each to its own and merge them in the end, in this way you need synchronization only once not "all the time"

Comment: Why do you use `std::vector` for concurrent `push_back` if you already use `tbb` (implied from your `parallel_for`)? `tbb::concurrent_vector` is designed for concurrent access.

Comment: Seems highly dependent on your exact details, but copying to separate vectors and merging sounds fine.

Comment: @PasserBy +1, in addition the using of separate vectors or even writing in the separated spans of the same vector will really [increase the performance](https://www.arbinada.com/en/node/1626).

Comment: @liliscent I tried your advice of using `tbb::concurrent_vector`, but found this resulted in **poorer performance**. I suspect it's implementation does not avoid false sharing and hence runs into the same problems as my simple approach.

Comment: @Walter I haven't used `tbb` for a while. But if I remember correctly, you should make sure to `push_back` a block of size bigger than cache line(64bytes). Did you consider this in your implementation?

Answer (score 0):

A decent way to do this is using thread-local vectors that are merged at the end. This answer (in particular the last code sample) would be a good duplicate if not for the fact that it uses OMP:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18671256/9528746

Edit: Changed to a better answer.

Comment: The main difference is not the OMP thing, but that I only collect selected items.