# Filtering vector onto another vector in Parallel

Tags: c++, dependencies, openmp, stdvector, pragma

I'm trying to filter a vector into another vector in parallel. My current setup generates too much overhead so it's even slower than serial. Concretely:

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for(int i = 0 ; i < a.size() ; i++){
   for(int j = 0 ; j < a.size() ; j++){
      if(meetsConditions(a[i], a[j])){
         std::vector<int> tmp = {i, j};
         #pragma omp critical
         b.push_back(tmp);
      }
   }
}
```

I'm saving the indices as I would like to later run a separate serial function on each couple that meets the condition:

```
for(auto element : b){
   doSmth(a[element[0]], a[element[1]]);
}
```

I tried doing it with a new empty vector, resizing it to a.size()*a.size(), allocating the elements using a third index that's in an atomic clause when it gets incremented, but that caused a data race (unless I saw it wrongly). How could I go about tackling this problem? Could maybe using lists make it easier? Or maybe storing pointers to these elements directly would make it easier? I'm really new to C++ so I'm not quite sure how I could get that to work.

Comment: I would parallelize only the first loop (no collapse), use a local `b_local` to each thread, and at the end concatenate all the `b_local` to the shared `b`. But I'm not sure it's worth parallelizing this, unless `meetsConditions()` has many computations

Comment: What would be the syntax to create the `b_local` and then concatenate it all? It sounds intimidating as I can't think of how different versions of a variable from each thread can be accessed.

Comment: Nesting vectors is a bad idea in most circumstances. As the inner vector seems to always have the size 2, using `std::array<int, 2>`, `std::pair<int, int>` or `std::tuple<int, int>` would be much better for cache locality.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `a.size()` is large enough, I would parallelize only the first loop (no collapse), use a local `b_local` to each thread, and at the end concatenate all the `b_local` to the shared `b`.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> b_local;
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0 ; i < a.size() ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < a.size() ; j++){
            if(meetsConditions(a[i], a[j])){
                std::vector<int> tmp = {i, j};
                b_local.push_back(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    #pragma omp critical
    b.insert(b.end(),b_local.begin(),b_local.end()); 
}
```

This should be more efficient, as the `critical` section is now outside of the loops and encountered only once per thread. `b_local` being private to each threads, no `critical` is needed when updating it.

But actually I'm not sure it's worth parallelizing this, unless meetsConditions() has many computations.

Comment: Alternatively, you can consider using a user defined reduction. E.g. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669296/c-openmp-parallel-for-loop-alternatives-to-stdvector/18671256#18671256).

Comment: @Laci You can not tell OMP that the reduction is non-commutative, so the local arrays may wind up in any order. Gross omission in the standard if you ask me. MPI does have a flag for this.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Thank you for the comment. You have now pointed out an advantage of manual reduction that did not occur to me. I would like to note in parentheses that the code in PierU's answer also does not keep the original order.

Comment: @Laci Indeed, and it was not my intention to keep the original order. To keep the order the insert should be inside the parallel loop, with an ordered pragma, and this may hurt the performances (depending on the workload in `meetconditions()`

Comment: @PierU I think you do not have to change the parallel loop, you just have to make sure that 1) the default `shedule(monotonic:static)` schedule is used. From OpenMP specification: "the `static` schedule ensures that the chunks are assigned to the threads in the team in a round-robin fashion in the order of the thread number.... when the `monotonic` modifier is specified then each thread executes the chunks that it is assigned in increasing logical iteration order."  2) The `b.insert` is performed in the right order (increasing thread number).

Comment: @Laci Assigning the chunks in the logical iteration order is not enough IMO. e.g. Iterations 0-4 are assigned to thread 0 and iterations 5-9 to thread 1, but thread 1 may reach the `insert` instruction before thread 0.

Comment: @PierU Yes, I agree, you need some additional code to make sure that `b.insert` is performed in the right order, but it is outside the parallel loop, so it does not hurt performance. (The main point of my comment was that you do not have to use an `ordered` clause, and it does not really hurt performance.)

Comment: @PierU Or you can use the ordered clause in a second loop, here is an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/xMPE4qxTT)

Comment: @Laci nice... but isn't the test always true?

Comment: @PierU Good point, it is not necessary..

Answer (score 0):

I would expect this code to run slower, as you have a a critcal section that is going to force the b.push_back(tmp) to run in a single thread.

Perhaps look to remove the critcal section and instead write the results directly to an already appropriatly sized b, something like:

```
vector<std::vector<int>> b;
b.resize(a.size() * a.size());

#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++) {
        if (meetsConditions(a[i], a[j])) {
            std::vector<int> tmp = { i, j };
            b.at((i*a.size())+j) = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Wouldn't there be a data race?

Comment: Thanks @PierU for the comment, I don't have enough rep yet to add comments to the original post, otherwise I would have done so.

Comment: I understand that it can be frustating to not be able to comment (I was frustrated as well), but it's not a good enough reason to post answers that should be comments.

Comment: The reason why this isn't an answer is that it is not really filtering. When you iterate about the result, you have to test again for each "element" if it was filled.

Comment: @Paleonix At the beginning there was no code in the answer.

Comment: @PierU One can debate if it is not an answer or a bad one, but just from the algorithmic side this is not filtering (stream compaction). And from the practical side `a.size()` could well be big enough for the allocation and initialization of `b` to to be a big waste/bottleneck which is the reason to do filtering in the first place.

Comment: @paleonix agree...

Comment: @paleonix I agree with you both, I missed the filtering point completely and focused on resolving the Parallel issue. I'm still new to SO, but I'll get better.